# Joomla 4 - hide custom fields in category blog

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-field, category-blog

I am using some custom fields at article level. These are also showing on the category blog view. How do I disable these? Am I being stupid or do I really need to create an override for such a trivial thing?

Many thanks